flutter_tools.stamp rebuilds automatically after deletion (want to fix the Flutter web XMLHttpRequest error on API call)
i was having this error:

ERROR: Dio error: The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer. This indicates an error which most likely cannot be solved by the library.
DartError: DioException [connection error]: The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer. This indicates an error which most likely cannot be solved by the library.

and i finally found a fix on stackover flow
How to solve flutter web api cors error only with dart code?

Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp

Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.

Find '--disable-extensions' and comment it

Add '--disable-web-security'


but after multiple tries i found no luck so check my flutter_tools.stamp if it was there and found out it was there after deletion and each time i delete it android studio rebuild it again. how can i delete it permanently or any alternative solution for my error?

I want a fix for my error of XMLHttpRequest
